# Getting nth smallest number location in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Pretty basic question but I can't seem to find any examples of how to solve it in Javascript.

I would like to create a function where you pass a number representing "n" and it returns the location of the nth smallest number in the array.

For instance, if I did:

```
array = [5,6,1,1,1,8]
n = 3
location = nth_smallest(array, n)
```

Location would then be equal to 4, because the third lowest number is 1 however I would like to skip the first several duplicates of that number.

The common solution to finding the location of the nth smallest number is by doing:

```
array = [5,6,1,1,1,8]
n = 3
nth_lowest = array.slice(0).sort()[n]
location = $.inArray(nth_lowest, array)
```

However the problem is that it will always return the location being 2 because it knows that the third smallest number is 1 but the inArray function doesn't care about duplicates.

Is there any way to do this, possibly without using the sort function? It seems to take up a lot of processing and this is a function that will be run quite often.

Comment: "to find any examples of how to solve it in Javascript" --- that's because the programming is when you create an algorithm on a paper and then program it, not google and copy-paste

Comment: There are surely other ways, but all of them are at least `O(n)` (since you have to compare every number in the array). Whether or not this is going to be slower or faster than using `.sort`, you can find out by profiling the code: http://jsperf.com/.

Comment: Zerkms, there are several reasons why I would like an example. I don't believe in reinventing the wheel, if the wheel is already invented then chances are its more efficient than I would have done. People also learn differently from each other, I learn best from examples and deconstructing it to understand the authors intention. I also don't believe copypasta is inherently wrong, its just using the tools out there to accomplish goals faster.

I don't see how it's at all productive to say learn to program on a site thats intended to help people solve programming problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// remap array as pairs of value and index
// e.g. change [5, 6, 1] to [[5, 0], [6, 1], [1, 2]]
var augmented_array = array.map(function(val, index) { return [val, index]; });
// sort pairs by the first position, breaking ties by the second
augmented_array.sort(function(a, b) {
    var ret = a[0] - b[0];
    if (ret == 0) ret = a[1] - b[1];
    return ret;
});
// example array will now be [[1, 2], [5, 0], [6, 1]]
// so we get the location by just looking at the second position of a pair
var location = augmented_array[n - 1][1];
```

If you want the last location having that value, after the sort do:

```
var position = n - 1;
while (position < augmented_array.length - 1 &&
       augmented_array[position][0] == augmented_array[position + 1][0]) {
  ++position;
}
var location = augmented_array[position][1];
```

Or if you want the first location, do:

```
var position = n - 1;
while (position > 0 &&
       augmented_array[position][0] == augmented_array[position - 1][0]) {
  --position;
}
var location = augmented_array[position][1];
```

Of course, `lastIndexOf` or `indexOf`, as suggested by one of the other answers would result in less code.

Comment: Thank you, this is wonderful. It totally makes sense that you would have to resort it while still holding on to the original position.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for the position of the *last* instance of the n-th lowest number? If so, try this:

```
array = [5,6,1,1,1,8];
n = 3;
nth_smallest = array.slice(0).sort()[n];
location = array.lastIndexOf(nth_smallest); // assumes non-ancient browser and/or shim
```

A haxy shim of `lastIndexOf` could be done like so:

```
function lastIndexOf(array,item) {
    return array.join("\x00").match(new RegExp(".*\x00"+item+"\x00"))[0].split("\x00").length-1;
}
```

This shim would need calling like so: `location = lastIndexOf(array,nth_smallest);`

Comment: That's not the problem. While `sort` is in-place, it also returns a reference to the array. The OP seems to want to get the last index of an element in an array, not the first one.

Comment: In that case, just replace `indexOf` with `lastIndexOf`

Comment: Yes. Still, `nth_lowest = array.slice(0).sort()[n]` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help though, I can see how my wording threw you off

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [9,3,4,5,3,4,6,7,8,];

arr.sort((a,b)=>{return a-b});
console.log(arr[arr.length-1]);
arr.sort((a,b)=>{return a-b});
console.log(arr[0]);
```

> to  find lowest number or highest number in array first you need to sort any array then array will be short sequence after the sort any array always in index (`arr[0]`) will be lowest number in any array and (`arr[arr.lenght-1]`) always highest number because we sort in sequnece
> thanks...